# Exit from shell script after execution via maven

Tags: shell, maven-3

I am executing below shell script (`my.sh`) via maven as shown below.

```
#!/bin/sh
oc login "https://server-name:8443" --insecure-skip-tls-verify--
echo "Enter userid password"
UN="username"
PWD="password"
-u $UN -p $PWD
oc project dev1
oc port-forward image-name 1521:1521 && exit
```

POM

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>my-exec</id>
                <phase>initialize</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <executable>sh</executable>
            <arguments>
                <argument>-c</argument>
                <argument>${project-home}/resources/my.sh</argument>
            </arguments>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

But the problem is when run mvn command ( `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=it`)

then terminal stops at `Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:1521 -> 1521` and stuck there without move forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the last line as below it worked.

```
nohup oc port-forward image-name 1521:1521 > /dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null &
echo
```

the >/dev/null pipes the parent log output to a void directory
it's a workaround for starting a background process easily

`nohup`  - disconnects the inputs and outputs of the background sub-process being launched from the parent process and tells the sub-process not to respond to HUP (hangup) signal